# ASP.NET Core 2.0 Web API Receiving/Sending Json requests from ionic 3

Tags: c#, angular, typescript, asp.net-core, ionic3

I have an ASP.NET Core 2.0 Web API Integrated with ionic 3.
I'm having problems receiving JSON data sent from ionic 3 App, Here is sample code:-

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Headers } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import { AlertController, LoadingController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { FCM } from '@ionic-native/fcm';
@Injectable()
export class ServerProvider {
private baseurl = "http://localhost:9681/api";
private api: String[] = new Array();

public loader: any;
constructor(public fcm: FCM, public http: Http, public alertCtrl: 
AlertController, public loadingCtrl: LoadingController) {
this.api['auth'] = 'Authentication';
this.api['agency'] = 'Agencies';
this.api['user'] = 'Users';
this.api['route'] = 'Routes';
this.api['token'] = 'Tokens';
this.api['notification'] = 'Notifications';
this.api['salepoint'] = 'Salepoints';
}

ServerRequest(api, request, data) {
return new Promise((resolve) => {
  let headers = new Headers();
  headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=UTF-8');
  this.http.get(this.baseurl  + "/" + this.api[api] + "/", {headers: headers}).map(res => res.json()).subscribe((result) => {
    resolve(result);
    console.log(result);
  }, (error) => {
    console.log(error); this.CreateAlert("Error", error, [
      {
        text: 'Close',
        handler: () => {
          this.loader.dismiss();
        }
      }
    ]);
  }, () => {
    this.loader.dismiss();
  });
});
}
```

Backend:-

```
[Route("api/Authentication")]
public class AuthenticationController : Controller
{
    IConfiguration _configuration;

    public AuthenticationController(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        _configuration = configuration;
    }
    [HttpGet]
    public JsonResult GetUser(JsonResult json)
    {
        AgencyUsers agencyusers = new AgencyUsers(_configuration);
        return Json(agencyusers.GetUser(json));
    }
}
```

I receive the following error:-

> An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
>   InvalidOperationException: Could not create an instance of type 
>   'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.JsonResult'. Model bound complex types must
>   not be abstract or value types and must have a parameterless
>   constructor.

What is the correct way to receive (serialize and deserialize JSON) and send back JSON (data or errors)?

Comment: Your ionic app isn't actually sending anything.   If you want to send some data in the body of your request then `GET` is the wrong type of request.  You should either include the parameters in your URL for a GET request (e.g. `http://example.com/api/Authentication?id=1` ) or for a request with a JSON body, switch to `POST` or `PUT` instead

Comment: Thank you, I have done a lot of modification to the code and now it's working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a lot of digging and modifications, I have finally got the API to work fine.
In case someone ran into a problem similar to mine, Here what I did:-

1. At Ionic, I have changed the HTTP request from GET to POST.

   ```
   ServerRequest(api, request, data) {
   return new Promise((resolve) => {
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=UTF-8');
   this.http.post(this.baseurl  + "/" + this.api[api] + "/" + request, JSON.stringify(data),{headers:headers}).map(res => res.json()).subscribe((result) => { ... });}
   ```
2. At Backend, Used [newtonsoft](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json) (JObject) Which saved me a lot of head that JsonResult causes, Then Changed Method type to IActionResult.

   ```
   [HttpPost("GetAgencyUser")]
   public IActionResult GetAgencyUser([FromBody]JObject request)
   {
       try
       {
           if (request["id"] == null)
           {
               return Ok("id is not defined or incorrect JSON format");
           }

           AgencyUsersMethods agencyusers = new AgencyUsersMethods(_configuration);
           var result = agencyusers.GetAgencyUser(request);

           if (result == null)
           {
               return Ok("User not Found");
           }
           else
           {
               return Ok(result);
           }

       }
       catch (Exception ex)
       {
           return BadRequest(ex.Message);
       }

   }
   ```